# GAE NDB Datastore: does a single put affect the whole entity?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

When using the Google App Engine NDB datastore does altering and putting one property of an entity affect the whole thing?

For example I have a video entity:

```
class Video(ndb.Model):
    title = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)
    category = ndb.StringProperty(required = True)

    original_video_ref = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()
    webm_video_ref = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()
    mp4_video_ref = ndb.BlobKeyProperty()
```

And I let the user edit the title and category whenever they want and I put out a process on the Task Queue to take the original video and return it to me in webm and mp4 formats.  This process takes a variable amount of time but can occur right when the user is editing it, and likely will, so I was wondering if I can have two, nearly simultaneous, puts on different properties of an entity without interfering with each other or needing to use transactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

A put is for the entire entity.  There is no partial update.

Comment: Okay, what do you think the best way to prevent this would be?  My main concern is that right when the user clicks to submit their changes that the server returns the video_refs and the user's changes are overridden or the video_refs are.

Comment: Split the entity up, a part updated by the processing a part by the user.  You can come up with more sophistacted locking, roll forward models etc... but this would probably be the simplest thing to do.

Comment: Handle both of the the updates in a transactions, and retry if the transaction fails.

Comment: Yeah, this is what transactions are for.